# Layout weight not working in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

got an Android problem that I can't figure out and so I'm here asking for another set of eyes :D. I have a fragment where I'm trying to display a map and a listview side by side when in landscape and top down when in portrait mode. Now it works as expected when it's in landscape orientation, but for some reason, when it's in portrait mode, the map is taking more room than the weight I have listed down. Thoughts? Below are the xml layouts for both landscape and portrait, as well as the fragment code and some screenshots of how it looks currently. From my experience, it should work as I expect it to, not how it is currently. Thanks again! :)

**XML Landscape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMapSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/npecCarbon"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeHolderMapView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewTicketSearchResults"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/label_no_data"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/npecWhite"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML Portrait**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMapSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/npecCarbon"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeHolderMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewTicketSearchResults"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/label_no_data"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/npecWhite"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment Code**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeHolderMapView, mapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    if(mapResults == null) {
        mapResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        mapResults.add("One");
        mapResults.add("Two");
        mapResults.add("Three");
        mapResults.add("Four");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> simpleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, mapResults.toArray(new String[mapResults.size()]));
    listViewSearchResults.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}
```

**Screenshots**
[Imgur album of screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT2XN.jpg)

**Update**
I was able to achieve the effect I want, but without relying on the weight properties. For the portrait layout, I give the container for the map view a height equal to half the display height and since the weight of the list view is working, it automatically fills the remaining half of the screen.

**Height Code**

```
private void calculateNewHeightForMap() {
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    if(size.y > size.x) { //We're in portrait mode, calculate height
    LayoutParams mapParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, size.y / 2);
    frameLayoutMapPlaceHolder.setLayoutParams(mapParams);
    }
```

While this will technically always work for me and while it does achieve the same result, I am still curious as to why the weight for the map part is seemingly ignored

Comment: may be you might need to define a customize layout for portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

try by adding `layout_weight=".20"` to list view in portrait mode

Comment: Interesting result. Applying this weight to the listview's container actually gave the list more room, not much (enough so that I can see three items from the list). Applying anything larger than 0.2 doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding weightSum="2" to the root LinearLayout.

Comment: Applying a weight sum of 2 had no change to the problem, however when I add a weight sum of 3 or 4, the container of the listview gets smaller (as it should), but the map's container gets larger (when it shouldn't) XD

Answer (score 0):

DOESN'T MATTER WHAT WEIGHT SUM U GAVE.
AS THE WEIGHT SUM U WILL APPLY ON ROOT WILL CONSIDER AS 100% ,THROUGH OUT, AND U HAVE TO DIVIDE IT ACCORDING TO IT ,CONSIDERING IT TO BE 100% IN ROOT LAYOUT.
AND APPLY LAYOUT WEIGHT IN CHILD OR STEM COMPONENT TO DIVIDE IT ACCORDINGLY RESPECTIVE OF ROOT.